# Why is my checkout in my multi store setup behind the url "/default/"?

Tags: magento-1.8, multistore, store-view

We have an API plugin and I'm currently testing it with multiple store fronts, but I've noticed that it gets put behind the URL part `/default/` instead of just starting at the "root" of the url. The same goes for the `/checkout/onepage`, this becomes `/default/checkout/onepage`.
Why is this and how can I disable it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most probably you have "Add Store Code to Urls" set to "Yes".
Go to the backend to `System->Configuration->Web->Url Options` and change it to `No`.

Comment: That was it, thanks again Marius! You are always so helpful :)